# Springboot project doesn't work after changing from 1.4.2.REALESE to 2.1.7.REALESE

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

well my problem came when I change My pom.xml version of my spring-boot project from 1.4.2.RELEASE to 2.1.7 RELEASE.

When I use the  2.1.7 RELEASE Doesnt work, on the other side when I use the 1.4.2.RELEASE it works fine. 1.4.2.RELEASE

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

I use eclipse IDE for developing , I already clean up the project and updated it as well , but still not working

I need to use this version because Im triying to use JWT so I need to use spring boot 2. Thanks

So what should I do?

Here is my pom.xml

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.hellokoding.springboot.jpa</groupId>
<artifactId>jpa-hibernate</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>navalWar</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>


<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <!-- This is a web application -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Tomcat embedded container -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Need this to compile JSP, tomcat-embed-jasper version is not working, 
        no idea why -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring data JPA, default tomcat pool, exclude it -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- HikariCP connection pool -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>



</dependencies>



<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Package as an executable jar/war -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Thanks
for your time.

Comment: What the error did you get? Add stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following Steps:

```
Replace dependency 1.4.2.RELEASE To 2.1.7 RELEASE

Right Click on pom.xml Then
Select Run As --> Click - Maven clean Then
Select Run As -->Click - Maven Install 
And Test It...
```

Comment: Thanks bro It works fine :D